# Как построить запрос к бд django

Tags: python, django

Суть вот в чем: Есть магазин, на странице поиска товаров есть фильтр по сезонам. Пользователь может выбрать один из четырех сезонов, может выбрать несколько, а может вообще не выбрать ни одного. Как во вьюхе сделать так, чтобы django фильтровала товары из бд по всем указаным сезонам, если они указаны, а если не указаны то вообще не учитывала этот параметр? Или подскажите хотя бы: в какую сторону гуглить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Product.object.filter(filter_seasons and Q(season__in=filter_seasons) or Q())
# или
res = Product.objects.all()
if form.cleaned_data['filtered_seasons']:
    res = res.filter(season__in=form.cleaned_data['filtered_seasons'])
```

---

PS: Присылайте хоть какую то часть кода, иначе вопрос отправят на доработку из-за недостатка информации для ответа